# How can I convert a string "True" to boolean. Python

Tags: python

So I have this data that list of True and False for example

```
tf = ['True', 'False', 'False']
```

how can I convert tf to a bool. Once I `print(tf[0])` it prints

```
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ast` module:

```
import ast
tf = ['True', 'False', 'False']
print(type(ast.literal_eval(tf[0])))
print(ast.literal_eval(tf[0]))
```

Result:

```
<class 'bool'>
True
```

[Ast Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

[Literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a dictionary to map the strings and boolean values

```py
tf = ['True', 'False', 'False']
toBool = {'True':True,'False':False}
print(toBool[tf[0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare each element of the `tf` list with `True` or `False`

```
for idx, val in enumerate(tf):
    if val == "True":
        tf[idx] = True
    else:
        tf[idx] = False
```

Comment: `tf = [val == 'True' for val in tf]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use: `eval(tf[0])` for that task.

Comment: `bool('False')` also returns `True`.

Comment: Yeah my mistake. Now I updated. This work

Comment: Never use `eval()` on data!

Comment: If I am wrong plz correct me. We do not use eval  because it can cause injections from malicious users right? Are there any other reasons. Asking this for just learn.

Comment: @YJR Correct. And for me it often makes the code harder to read.